# Kotlin Inheritance

Tags: generics, inheritance, kotlin

I'm currently learning to split my messy code into DDD (note, learning) paradigm. The entities (`IEntity`, `IUser`) is domain layer is made up of interface, which then implemented at the Data layer (`BaseEntity`, `User`). Access to data is through the repository pattern. But as I defined for `IUserRepository` to return `IUser`, at the data layer I have to manually cast it `User` back to `IUser` to match the return signature.

How can I avoid the casting? Thank you.

**Domain layer**

```
interface IEntity
{
    var id: Long?
    var name: String?
}

interface IUser : IEntity
{
}

interface IBaseRepository<T: IUser>
{
    fun get(id: Long): Observable<T?>
}

interface IUserRepository : IBaseRepository<IUser>
{
}
```

**Data layer**

```
abstract class BaseEntity() : IEntity
{
    @SerializedName("id")
    override var id: Long? = null

    @SerializedName("full_name")
    override var name: String? = null
}

class User() : BaseEntity(), IUser
{
}

interface UserRetrofitApi
{
    @GET("user/{uuid}/")
    fun get(id: Long): Observable<User?>
}

class UserRepository(private val _api: UserRetrofitApi) : IUserRepository
{
    override fun get(id: Long): Observable<IUser?> {
        return _api.get(id) as Observable<IUser?> // How to avoid casting here without resorting to generic UserRepository<T: IUser>
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any special constrain on `UserRetrofitApi::get`? You just need to change it into `fun get(id: Long): Observable<IUser?>` if there is none.

Comment: @glee8e, see my respond below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your `get` function in the base repository as follows:

```
fun get(id: Long): Observable<out T?>
```

and likewise change the `get` function in `UserRepository` to:

```
override fun get(id: Long): Observable<out IUser?> {
    return _api.get(id)
}
```

See [the docs on variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#declaration-site-variance) for more information.

Comment: I've read through the doc and it make a lot sense as compared to reading it the first time. I've tried it out and it works.

A follow up question would be that the repository need to support CRUD operations and I cannot declare the `UserRepository` to be covariant. I've read through the **use-site variance** and **type projections** but I not able to solve my own question as I'm passing a single object rather than collection/array of objects as per example given.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you just need to change you return the result of `UserRetroFitApi.get` to `Observable<IUser?>`.

```
class UserRetrofitApi
{
    fun get(id: Long): Observable<IUser?> {
        val user = User()
        user.id = 1
        user.name = "User 1"
        return Observable.just(user)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) to interacting with the server api. From what I understand, the Retrofit object need to be a class with default constructor and it will help to perform the serialization and serialization from and to json object.

I've updated the sample code to reflect the actual Retrofit interface.